# Java Function similar to word game, last letter = first letter of next word

Tags: java, sorting, arguments

The function main accepts an array of strings as an arguement, and will print a single line of output. the output will be the input in an order such that the first letter of each string is the same as the last letter of the previous string but also the last letter of last string is same as first letter of first string. If no order exists that include all strings, then the code will print no solution

Example input and outputs:

input: squirrel eyes klondlike lasik

output: squirrel lasik klondlike eyes

input: why cant we dance

output: NO SOLUTION

input: apple tampa elephant

output:apple elephant tampa

I have written most of the code however my sorting method does not work for every test case because of the way it is written, would anyone be able to help??

```
public class Ring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean a = isFlip(args);


        if(a) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("NO SOLUTION");
        }

    }

    public static boolean isFlip(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i <args.length ; i++) {
            args[i]=args[i].toLowerCase();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length-1 ; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j <args.length ; j++) {

                if (args[i].charAt(0)==(args[j].charAt(args[j].length()-1))){
                    String s= args[j];
                    args[j]=args[i];
                    args[i]=s;
                }
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i <args.length-1 ; i++) {
            if((args[i+1].charAt(0)!=(args[i].charAt(args[i].length()-1)))){
                 return false;
            }

        }
        if(args[args.length-1].charAt(args[args.length-1].length()-1)!=args[0].charAt(0)) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think *maybe* I get what you're trying to do, but just to be sure, can you edit your question to include some example inputs/outputs?

Comment: sorry about that, i edited it

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Another clarifying question.  Do you want to allow for more than one word in the input having the same first letter, and/or the same last letter?  Because if you allow for this, your task will be exceedingly more difficult to code because your code will have to explore multiple permutations and then backtrack when it can't find a solution with one permutation.  But if you disallow it, you will then have to decide how to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the recursive approach. The main idea is check for every word is other words could be in the chain.

```
private String[] findRing(String... words) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = words[i];
        String[] result = findRingForHeadAndTail(word, dropElementWithIndex(i, words));
        if ((result.length == words.length - 1) &&
                (word.charAt(0) == result[result.length - 1].charAt(result[result.length - 1].length() - 1))) { //word started from last letter in tail
            return concatHeadAndTail(word, result);
        }
    }
    return new String[]{"NO SOLUTION"};
}

private String[] findRingForHeadAndTail(
        String head, //first word
        String... tail //other words
) {
    if (tail.length == 0) { // if we don't have other words then just return empty array
        return new String[0];
    }

    if (tail.length == 1) { // if we have just one word in tail
        if (tail[0].charAt(0) == head.charAt(head.length() - 1)) { //and this word begins with last letter in head
            return tail; //return this tail
        } else {
            return new String[0]; //otherwise return empty array
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tail.length; i++) { // for every word
        String word = tail[i];
        if (word.charAt(0) == head.charAt(head.length() - 1)) { // if this word begins with last letter in head
            String[] result = findRingForHeadAndTail( //recursive call for 
                    word, //picked word
                    dropElementWithIndex(i, tail) // all other words in tail
            ); 
            if (result.length == tail.length - 1) { // if recursive call returns the same amount of words as we passed there as tail
                return concatHeadAndTail(word, result); //return array {head, tail}
            }
        }
    }
    return new String[0];
}

//returns array as {head, tail}
private String[] concatHeadAndTail(String head, String... tail) {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(head), Stream.of(tail)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[tail.length + 1]);
}

//removes element with index i from words
private String[] dropElementWithIndex(int i, String... words) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        if (j != i) {
            result.add(words[j]);
        }
    }
    return result.toArray(new String[words.length - 1]);
}
```

And output for:

```
@Test
public void findRing() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("squirrel", "eyes", "klondlike", "lasik")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("why", "cant", "we", "dance")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("apple", "tampa", "elephant")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("apple", "elephant", "tampa")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("elephant", "apple", "tampa")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("alfa", "alfa", "beta")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("alfa", "alfa")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRing("alfa", "alfa", "bravo")));
}
```

is:

```
[squirrel, lasik, klondlike, eyes]
[NO SOLUTION]
[apple, elephant, tampa]
[apple, elephant, tampa]
[elephant, tampa, apple]
[NO SOLUTION]
[alfa, alfa]
[NO SOLUTION]
```

**UPDATE** Previous solution has complexity  O(n!) in worse case. Different solution was suggested by [FDesu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3123517/fdesu) and is based on one of properties of [Adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

> If A is the adjacency matrix of the directed or undirected graph G, then the matrix An (i.e., the matrix product of n copies of A) has an interesting interpretation: the element (i, j) gives the number of (directed or undirected) walks of length n from vertex i to vertex j.

This algorithm has complexity O(n^4), but also has additional requirements for memory, because we should store all possible paths.

```
private void findRingWithMatrix(String... words) {
    System.out.println("For example: " + Arrays.toString(words));
    boolean[][] initialAdjacencyMatrix = new boolean[words.length][words.length];
    List<String[]> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    //Build initial adjacency matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            initialAdjacencyMatrix[i][j] = (i != j) && (couldBeInChain(words[i], words[j]));
            //if node is reachable
            if (initialAdjacencyMatrix[i][j]) {
                //put this path to possible paths
                paths.add(new String[]{words[i], words[j]});
            }
        }
    }

    //create temporary copy of matrix to multiply
    boolean[][] tempAdjacencyMatrix = initialAdjacencyMatrix.clone();

    //We should multiply matrix N-1 times, because first step in graph we've already done on previous step
    for (int n = 1; n < words.length; n++) {
        boolean[][] bufferAdjacencyMatrix = new boolean[words.length][words.length];

        List<String[]> newPathes = new ArrayList<>();

        //multiply matrices (next step and initial). In result we get [true] in node which is reachable from first node in N steps
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < words.length; k++) {
                    bufferAdjacencyMatrix[i][j] |= (tempAdjacencyMatrix[i][k] && initialAdjacencyMatrix[k][j]);
                }
                //if node reachable
                if (bufferAdjacencyMatrix[i][j]) {
                    //create new path and put it list of possible paths
                    for (String[] path : paths) {
                        if (couldBeInChain(path[path.length - 1], words[j])) {
                            String[] newPath = new String[path.length + 1];
                            System.arraycopy(path, 0, newPath, 0, path.length);
                            newPath[newPath.length - 1] = words[j];
                            newPathes.add(newPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        paths = removeDuplicates(newPathes);
        System.out.println("Step #" + n);
        printMatrix(bufferAdjacencyMatrix);
        tempAdjacencyMatrix = bufferAdjacencyMatrix;
    }

    boolean isRing = true;

    //Ring could be just if after (N-1) multiplications we have [true] in main diagonal.
    //In other words, can reach every node in N steps.
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        isRing = tempAdjacencyMatrix[i][i];
        if (!isRing) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isRing) {
        System.out.println("NO SOLUTION");
        return;
    } else {

        System.out.println("Found solutions:");
        for (String[] path : paths) {
            //we are interested just in solutions when first node is equals to last one
            if (path[0].equals(path[path.length - 1])) {
                String[] toPrint = new String[path.length - 1];
                System.arraycopy(path, 0, toPrint, 0, toPrint.length);
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(toPrint));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("==============================");
}

private boolean couldBeInChain(String first, String second) {
    return first.charAt(first.length() - 1) == second.charAt(0);
}

private List<String[]> removeDuplicates(List<String[]> newPathes) {
    return newPathes
            .stream()
            .map(Arrays::asList)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), new Function<Set<List<String>>, List<String[]>>() {
                @Override
                public List<String[]> apply(Set<List<String>> lists) {
                    List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (List<String> list : lists) {
                        result.add(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }));
}

private void printMatrix(boolean[][] matrix) {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");

    for (boolean[] row : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: Does this code handle something like input: "apple", "tampa", "tad", "dot", "elephant", with output: "apple", "elephant", "tad", "dot", "tampa"?

Comment: @TJamesBoone yes, checked. output is `[apple, elephant, tad, dot, tampa]`

Comment: Sweet.  That means it can handle this problem.  Kudos for great use of recursion!

Comment: Thank you very much this is very helpful!
I guess doing it with out recursion would not work, but ill figure a way to use this while accepting the strings as args, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
class T
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
int k=1;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
String str=sc.nextLine(); 
String[] word=str.split(" "); 
StringBuilder str1=new StringBuilder(word[0]); 
while(str1.toString().length()!=str.length())
{ 
for(int j,i=1;i<word.length;i++)
{ 
for(j=1;j<word.length;j++)
{
if((str1.toString()).endsWith(Character.toString(word[j].charAt(0))))
{ 
str1.append(" "+word[j]);
} 
} 
}
break;
}
for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++)
{
    if((str1.toString()).indexOf(word[i])<0)
    {
        str1.insert(0,word[i]+" ");
        k=k+1;
    }
}
if(k==word.length)
    System.out.println(str);
else
    System.out.println("NO SOLUTION"); 
} 
}
```